# apps on my tab are not connected on the internet but the browser does

Tags: factory-reset

I am using an android tablet and apple iPad2. I just noticed this morning That my apps on my tablet aren't working but my browser does. Now I'm using my iPad and everything is working fine, they are connected on the same WiFi so I assume my connection is not the problem. My tab is working properly last night and didn't do anything on it before the problem.

Date/time are also properly set and I already did a factory reset twice.